# I am trying to access an API using RestSharp in C# but the recomnended way doesn't work anymore

Tags: c#

I was trying to access an API using the way the site recommends but restSharp doesn't contain all methods that were used anymore (specificaly Get and IRestResonse)

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using RestSharp;
var client = new RestClient("Link");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("DB-Client-Id", "clientId");
request.AddHeader("DB-Api-Key", "clientSecret");
request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: maybe they changed the API? How should anyone know when we have absolutely no idea about what "the API" actually is?

Comment: IRestResponse was deprecated, so you either need to downgrade RestSharp or make the code work in the new way, which isn't so hard.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to official RestSharp documentation, especially ["Migration from legacy"](https://restsharp.dev/v107/#restsharp-v107) part. There were significant changes of RestSharp interfaces in v107, happened 2 years ago.

In current version (v110.2 at the moment of answer) your code roughly could look like:

```
var client = new RestClient("Link");
var request = new RestRequest("", Method.Get);
request.AddHeader("DB-Client-Id", "clientId");
request.AddHeader("DB-Api-Key", "clientSecret");
request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```